# Find value of infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find value of
>   $${{7}\over {9}}\times {{26}\over {28}}\times {{63}\over {65}}\times \dots \infty$$

I can see that the terms take the form $${{n^{3}-1}\over {n^{3}+1}}\ \ \text{for} \ \ n=2,3, \dots$$
How to prove that the product converges?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is almost a shame that these algebraic simplifications are available since to determine the *convergence* of this infinite product one can rely on more basic and more general tools (which would probably be more useful to this OP than the clever trick).

Comment: You're probably right there, @Did.

Comment: For part of the telescoping, use the fact that $n^2-n+1=(n-1)^2+(n-1)+1$.

Comment: OP: What are the infinite products such that you can prove they converge?

Comment: It is product of the form $a_1.a_2.a_3.\cdots$. If we take partial products, then we get a decreasing sequence of positive numbers, which must converge.

Comment: It converges to 2/3, may be proved using Gama function - See:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html

Comment: Are you aware, mathgirl, of a theorem relating $\prod(1+a_n)$ to $\sum a_n$?

Comment: @Groups No. An infinite product such that the sequence of its partial products converges to zero is not said to be convergent.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey To replace "$\times \dots$ to infinity" (awkward but clear) by "$\times \dots \infty$" (squarely incorrect) in the question is frankly unwise.

Comment: The question as edited does not make sense.  I'm voting to close the question as *unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: @Did: I don't know why the limit of partial sums should be non-zero to say that the infinite product converges. What I wrote was "most natural" that can be.

Comment: @Groups To dispel your doubts (and to get rid of "natural" definitions no one uses), see second sentence in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{(n+1)n+1}{n(n-1)+1},$$ the partial product would be $$\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{2}{N(N+1)}\cdot\frac{(N+1)N+1}{3},$$ if $N>3$. Let $N\to\infty$, then we get $$\prod_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac23.$$

---

The convergence is clear, but we can prove it before determining the partial product. Since in many cases to determine the partial product is impossible, the following theorem is useful:

> **Theorem**: Suppose $a_n>0$. $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

It is easy to see that the theorem also works when $-1<a_n<0$.

Many other related theorems can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product.

---

If the convergence of the product is known, one can determine the value of it formally, which is similar to the discussion above.

Comment: The product in the OP is not of the form $\prod(1+a_n)$ with $a_n>0$.

Comment: @Did Then consider $\frac{n^3+1}{n^3-1}$ instead.

Comment: Then explain that you do, in the answer (or state a more convenient theorem, dealing with $a_n$ of both signs).

Comment: @EclipseSun Can you please elaborate how did you got$ \prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$ equal to $\frac{2}{N(N+1)}\cdot\frac{(N+1)N+1}{3}$ . I am struck on this question and my question was linke dto thj equestion asked above but I am not able to deduce the line that I mentioned in your answer by myself. So, please help me!

Comment: @Ben You can compute $\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ and $\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n(n+1)+1}{n(n-1)+1}$ separately.